# SQLite: How to get handle from SQliteConnection using C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

How to get the database handle from SQLiteConnection to use with sqlite3_limit and all the other core functions of SQLite3 later on?

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.SQLite does not allow access to the database connection handle; you can use only those functions that are wrapped by its API.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the .NET wrapper of SQLite you're using. If you have one with source code that you can compile yourself, make the underlying handle public and access it in your client code. If you can't do that, you'll have to extract the underlying handle from the wrapper code via reflection - look for internal or private `SafeHandle`/`IntPtr` fields. Note that your wrapper may not be designed in a way that would allow it to work if you access the handle directly, as it may expect the handle to be in a particular state when the wrapped functionality is accessed via the wrapper and you break those expectations by manipulating the handle.